# replicate tables from mysql database to online hosting server having cpanel (5gbfree.com)

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I am looking for a way to mirror or replicate a local MySQL database to an online hosting website which is 5gbfree.com. I saw the master slave replication but don't know how to use it with an online server. Can you help me please ?

I tried setting the online database as the slave but it didn't work.

**problem**

I don't know how to configure the online database as the slave.

Comment: There's no way a free host is going to give you the level of access you need to adjust MySQL replication settings.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the `mysqld.ini` file? If not, it is not possible to configure replication. Replication configuration relies heavily on having access to the said file and additional configuration (e.g. Firewall, Range of IP Addresses to accept connections from, creating replication user account, restarting the service)

Your best bet is to export the data from your localhost and import them in your hosting provider.

Or, check with your provider. They might be able to help you.

Additional [reading](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-howto.html) here.

Comment: i could use export and import but the problem is i want to automate the process so that every 5 minutes or so the database is mirrored to the online host.

Comment: have you asked your provider if they can provide some sort of settings for you to set-up replication?